# Convert HTML headings and li elements into table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to convert a list into a table and use the preceding heading elements as table values? I am open to different solutions, but I feel like this could be done via Python and perhaps BeautifulSoup.

Here's the starting HTML structure:

```html
<h2>Category 1</h2>
        <h3>Option 1</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Option 2</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>D</li>
            <li>E</li>
            <li>F</li>
        </ul>
    
    <h2>Category 2</h2>
        <h3>Option 1</h3> <!--yes this option has the same title as the one above-->
        <ul>
            <li>G</li>
            <li>H</li>
            <li>I</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Option 3</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>J</li>
            <li>K</li>
            <li>L</li>
        </ul>
```

Here's the desired result:

```html
<table> 
        <tr>
            <td>Category 1</td>
            <td>Option 1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category 1</td>
            <td>Option 1</td>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category 1</td>
            <td>Option 1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category 1</td>
            <td>Option 2</td>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category 1</td>
            <td>Option 2</td>
            <td>E</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category 1</td>
            <td>Option 2</td>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category 2</td>
            <td>Option 1</td>
            <td>G</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category 2</td>
            <td>Option 1</td>
            <td>H</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category 2</td>
            <td>Option 1</td>
            <td>I</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category 2</td>
            <td>Option 3</td>
            <td>J</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category 2</td>
            <td>Option 3</td>
            <td>K</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category 2</td>
            <td>Option 3</td>
            <td>L</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Again, I am open to any solution. The end goal is to be able to produce a table or csv or something that can be copied into Excel easily, but unfortunately I am not starting with great source content for the format I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this in a number of ways, I went for parsing the data as a string and some basic regex using the pandas lib.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd # pip install pandas.
import numpy as np # pip install numpy 

html = """
    <h2>Category 1</h2>
    <h3>Option 1</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
    </ul>
 """
```

---

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(html),sep='|',header=None) 
print(df.head(3))
    
            0
0      <h2>Category 1</h2>
1        <h3>Option 1</h3>
2                     <ul>
3               <li>A</li>
```

---

```
#if you have lots of uncessary html you need to strip out
# df = df[df[0].str.contains('<li>|<h2>|<h3>')==True] 
#extract category.
df["category"] = df[0].str.extract("<h2>(.*)</h2>")[0].ffill().str.strip()
#extract option.
df["option"] = df[0].str.extract("<h3>(.*)</h3>")[0].ffill().bfill().str.strip()
#remove html tags and replace empty spaces with np.nan so we can drop them.
df[0] = (
    df[0]
    .replace("<[^<]+?>", "", regex=True)
    .str.strip()
    .replace("", np.nan, regex=True)
)

# remove blank rows & rows where the html col is equal to it self.
df = df.loc[ (df[0].ne(df['category']))  & (df[0].ne(df['option'])) ].dropna(how='any')

print(df[['category','option',0]])

      category    option  0
3   Category 1  Option 1  A
4   Category 1  Option 1  B
5   Category 1  Option 1  C
9   Category 1  Option 2  D
10  Category 1  Option 2  E
11  Category 1  Option 2  F
16  Category 2  Option 1  G
17  Category 2  Option 1  H
18  Category 2  Option 1  I
22  Category 2  Option 3  J
23  Category 2  Option 3  K
24  Category 2  Option 3  L
```

---

Finally, you can call `df.to_excel('file.xlsx',index=False)` to export the dataframe.